# MS Chart Width 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am displaying Column Chart based on dynamic data. I want to set the Chart width 100%. But MS chart does not allow to set it. Please can you suggest me how to resolve this issue. Because I want to set Bar width same for all series.

[image]

Comment: Work around for this issue is, I set width initially and when data is exceeding from the width then setting width at run time with multiply by any value like 100 OR 200 OR 300 and then set the width of the chart.

Answer (score 3):

Set your chart width to som larger number to allow clear rendering - say 1920px

Then add this bit of javascript to your page

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('<%=Chart1.ClientID %>').style.width = '95%'", 500);
```